# Can Watson OpenScale monitor models that are serving using AWS Lambda Function?

Tags: aws-lambda, ibm-watson, h2o, watson-openscale

H2O Driverless AI serves its models using AWS Lambda Function. I'm wondering if there's a possible integration between H2O and Watson OpenScale.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly with OOTB supported serv engines, but Watson OpenScale has a feature of supporting custom serv engines, documented in the below links, using which you can monitor the said models using AWS Lambda functions.

https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/ai-openscale?topic=ai-openscale-co-connect
https://developer.ibm.com/patterns/monitor-custom-machine-learning-engine-with-ai-openscale/
https://github.com/IBM/monitor-custom-ml-engine-with-watson-openscale

Thanks